# Simplify a Linq Map and Filter

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I am new to C# and unity. I have this line of code:

```
List<Unit> enemyUnits = hitColliders.Where((hc) =>
        {
            var u = hc.GetComponent<Unit>();
            return u && u.team != team;
        }).Select(c => c.GetComponent<Unit>()).ToList();
```

which is supposed to take all the hit colliders in range (calculated above), filter out the ones on my team (all the enemy ones), then grab the attached unit on them, and finally collect them into a list.

I hate how I have to call `c.GetComponent<Unit>()` twice. Is there a way to simlify this? I've tried a Select where I return the unit in the first lambda, but I end up with nulls for the ones that are not enemies.

Comment: `return u && u.team != team;` this won´t compile. Maybe you mean `return u != null && u.team != team;`?

Comment: As per [Microsoft's recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/performance-recommendations-for-unity#avoid-expensive-operations), you should avoid Linq in Unity. Although elegant, it's too expensive — unless you call it very rarely.

Comment: Didn't know that :( I guess I'll make the choice to either use it sparingly or go the more iterative approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the `Select` first, since you are not using `hc` in the `Where` other than calling `GetComponent<Unit>()`:

```
List<Unit> enemyUnits = hitColliders
        .Select(c => c.GetComponent<Unit>())
        .Where(u => u != null && u.team != team)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: "did you mean..." I assumed that objects were truthy and null was falsey... is that a bad assumption?

Comment: @Jeff That is a bad assumption. You meant to check if `u` is not null right?

Comment: `.Where(u => u?.team != team)` may also work, depending on your requirements